# VS Code can't find Python and interpreter

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, path, vscode-extensions

I searched everywhere, but did not find an answer. Since I think the answers are outdated because they use python.pythonPath and this does not exist anymore.
My problem is the following:
[image]

But I installed Python@3.10 already via homebrew (I have a mac M1 with macOS Monterey).
If I use ,,which python3'', I will get:
[image]

And here you can see the output of ,,echo $PATH'':
[image]

What should I do, so that the error message does not appear again??

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Extensions Library and download the Python Interpreter for VS Code. Make sure Python is installed on your PC.

If you still have problems, try reinstalling Python and VS Code.

Comment: I already installed the Python extension of Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on 'No Interpreter Selected' and then you can add a path to python[image]

If nothing else will work
[image]

Go on terminal and write your `python-path\python.exe python-file.y`.
If this works you can create a shell script inside of your folder and then put inside the python call. Then you can start your python file with the shell script.

Comment: I tried this, but the error message appears anyway... I used the path from the command ,,which python3''. Is that correct?

Comment: @ZPlaya7 Then I would try to instakll python as an extension. Maybe it works then

Comment: I did that too :/ The Python extension of Microsoft.

Comment: @ZPlaya7 I edited my answer and made a secon approach

Answer (score 0):

I think the above two answers have been well analyzed. If you can't solve the problem, you can refer to the [instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) of vsocde and reinstall python.